# show "product operation on paths induces a well defined operation on path homotopy classes"

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is from Munkres, Topology. I want to show that for $f,g \in \Omega(X,x_0)$, which is the set of all loops at base point $x_0$, that the following holds:

$$[f]*[g]=[f*g]$$
where $*$ is the usual binary operation defined on paths.

My source of confusion stems from interpreting the actual meaning of $=$ in the previous relationship. It is one thing to say that $[f]=[g]$ if $f\simeq g$ via some homotopy. On the other hand, I am under the impression that $[f]*[g]$ is also a *set consisting of the product of elements in the two equivalence classes* i.e. I am under the impression that $[f]*[g]:=\{j*k: j\in [f], k\in [k]\}$ from this it would be necessary to show that $h*m \in [f]*[g], h*m \in [f*g] $ and vice versa.

However the proof that Munkres provides only deals with showing that the product of path homotopies on the left side is the required path homotopy for the product of paths on the right hand side.

What is the formal interpretation of $[f]*[g]$ and how does it relate to the proof provided by Munkres?

Comment: No, $[f]*[g]$ is not what you claim, and I'd be surprised if Munkres said that. What it is, is the path homotopy class of $f'*g'$ for any $f'\in[f]$ and $g'\in[g]$.

Comment: Path homotopy class as in $[f]*[g]=\{[f'*g']:f'\in [f],g'\in[g] \}$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Munkres *defines* $[f]*[g] = [f * g]$ and proves that this is well-defined. In fact, he shows
$$\{ f' * g' \mid f' \in [f], g' \in [g] \} \subset  [f* g] .$$
In general you **do not** have $\{ f' * g' \mid f' \in [f], g' \in [g] \} = [f]*[g]$. As an example take $(X,x_0) = (S^1,1)$, where $S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert z  \rvert = 1 \}$. Let $f(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$ and $g(t) = f(1-t) = e^{-2\pi i t}$. Then $[f] * [g] = [e]$, where $e$ is the constant path $e(t) = 1$. However, there do not exist $f' \in [f], g' \in [g]$ such that $f' * g' = e$. This would only be possible if $f' = g' = e$, but it is well-known that $[f] \ne [e]$ and $[g] \ne [e]$.

The equation $[f]*[g] = \{ [f' * g'] \mid f' \in [f], g' \in [g] \}$ in your comment is also wrong. On the left hand side you have a *set of paths*, on the right hand side a *set of sets of paths*.

Comment: So if $[f]*[g] \neq \{f' *g' : f'\in [f], g'\in [g]\}$, why is the proof based on the first inclusion you mentioned?

Comment: The inclusion says that if you pick **any** representatives $f'$ of $[f]$ and $g'$ of $[g]$, then $f' * g'$ and $f * g$ are path homotopic. This shows that Munkres' definition of $[f] * [g]$ makes sense.However, in general you will find paths $u \in [f] * [g]$ which do not split as $u = f' * g'$.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify why $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ you defined do not belong to the same equivalence class?

Comment: Just to clarify your question: You ask why both $[f], [g]$ are not equal to $[e]$?

Comment: Hey, @PaulFrost in general $[f] * [g]$ doesn't make any sense but he is defining above it to be the set of all product $j*k$ where $j \in [f]$ and $k \in [g]$. So I think you are trying to say $[f] * [g] = \{ j*k : j \in [f], k\in [g] \} \neq [f*g]$. Right?

Comment: @Sushant Yes, that is the contents of my answer. The equivalence class of $f  * g$ contains (in general) more elements than those having the form $j * k$ with $j \in [f]$ and $k \in [g]$.

Comment: Ya, it's a nice observation. So in your third line, it should be $[f*g]$ , not $[f]*[g]$.

Comment: @Sushant We have $[f*g] = [f]*[g]$ *by Munkres' definition*. One could define $[f] \# [g] = \{ j* k \mid j \in [f], k \in [g] \}$ (this is what the OP suggests in his question), but this does not give us a multiplication because the result is not a full equivalence class.  We only get $[f] \# [g] \subset [f * g]$.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to show for well-definedness of $[f] \ast [g]$ is that if we take any representative $f' \simeq f$ and any $g' \simeq g$, then $f' \ast g' \simeq f \ast g$, i.e. we get the same homotopy class regardless of representatives. This common class is then defined to be the product.

The proof is on page 2 of [my note here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/09.pdf), where I also check all the axioms.